# Google maps : My+Location in URL does not translate in other languages

Tags: google-maps

I am using google maps as a store locator on my website, and i am using the "get directions" url code to help people find my products.

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&mrt=loc&t=m&saddr=My+Location&daddr=
```

This works fine, but it won't work for people using smartphones in another language than english.
the term "My Location" will not correspond to the localized french version of the google maps android or ios app, which is "Ma Position".

My question is : is there a universal term i can use to define the user's current position in my URL call?

I tried using Current+Location but is does not translate and the app returns the closest POI which's name is close to the words "Current Location", actually a flat renting company in french version of the app...

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal term. Just add a 'language' parameter in your URI request and put the preferred language. 
First check out the [supported languages](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport). French is "fr".

Here's a sample URI request with that added:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=fr
```

Here are more statements from the guide [Directions API Request Parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

> **language** — The language in which to return results. See the list of supported languages. Google often updates the supported languages,
>   so this list may not be exhaustive. If language is not supplied, the
>   API attempts to use the preferred language as specified in the
>   Accept-Language header, or the native language of the domain from
>   which the request is sent.
>
> The API does its best to provide a street address that is readable for
>   both the user and locals. To achieve that goal, it returns street
>   addresses in the local language, transliterated to a script readable
>   by the user if necessary, observing the preferred language. All other
>   addresses are returned in the preferred language. Address components
>   are all returned in the same language, which is chosen from the first
>   component. If a name is not available in the preferred language, the
>   API uses the closest match.
>
> The preferred language has a small influence on the set of results
>   that the API chooses to return, and the order in which they are
>   returned. The geocoder interprets abbreviations differently depending
>   on language, such as the abbreviations for street types, or synonyms
>   that may be valid in one language but not in another. For example,
>   utca and tér are synonyms for street in Hungarian.